# Leaflet zoom event direction

Tags: leaflet

Is it possible to find out whether the user zooms in or out when using a Leaflet *zoomstart* or *zoom* event?

```
map.on('zoomstart ', function() {

    console.log('I am zooming, but am I zooming in or out?');

});
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893070/detecting-if-is-zoom-in-or-zoom-out-with-leaflet/39896151